# WDS Internet works on a notebook but doesn't work on a Tablet

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking, wds

I set [WDS on TP-LINK Router](http://www.tp-link.com/en/article/?faqid=227)

When I connect to the router from my notebook I can use Internet but when I do it from my tablet Internet doesn't work but Wi-Fi connection is stable.

```
Main Router: ZyXEL P660HN
WDS Router: TP-LINK TL-WR741ND
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: There is no real WDS standard, and vendors' products do not always interoperate. If you want to do this, all the access points should be exactly the same hardware, and preferably exactly the same firmware revision.

Comment: This worked good some time but one day it broke and I tried repair it with help of the same instructions which I used when it worked.  I want to know what may be wrong with it and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I own the TP-LINK WR841ND and use it in the same scenario. Make sure that you enable WDS bridging in your TP-LINK and, most importantly, you need to disable DHCP on the TP-LINK. Could it be that you've set a static IP on your notebook while your tablet is set to obtain a DHCP address? Then this could be the problem.

Comment: The notebook and the tablet obtains IP by DHCP. On the TP-LINK DHCP is disabled.

Comment: Disabling the DHCP server in the bridge router solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Static IP address in your tablet. Is it Android? It can be set easily.

Default gateway: 192.168.1.1 (IP address of your primary wifi router)
IP: 192.168.1.xxx (anything that is not used already in your network)